# How to get URL query string on Next.js static site generation?

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, query-string, ssg

I want to get query string from URL on Next.js static site generation.

I found a solution on SSR but I need one for SSG.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can try using router.asPath and parse the query yourself with a library like query-string:

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4804#issuecomment-460754433

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17269

Answer (score 15):

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
    if(!router.isReady) return;
    const query = router.query;
  }, [router.isReady, router.query]);
```

It works.

Comment: Is it necessary to include router.query in the useEffect dependencies? It seems like router.isReady is enough

Comment: @camiblanch Only if you're using `router.query` inside the `useEffect`. Otherwise, you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers mentioned, since SSG doesn't happen at request time, you wouldn't have access to the query string or cookies in the context, but there's a solution I wrote a short article about it here https://dev.to/teleaziz/using-query-params-and-cookies-in-nextjs-static-pages-kbb

TLDR;

Use a middleware that encodes the query string as part of the path,

```
// middleware.js file
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { encodeOptions } from '../utils';

export default function middleware(request) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/my-page') {
    const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams
    const path = encodeOptions({
      // you can pass values from cookies, headers, geo location, and query string
      returnVisitor: Boolean(request.cookies.get('visitor')),
      country: request.geo?.country,
      page: searchParams.get('page'),
    })

    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`/my-page/${path}`, request.nextUrl))
  }
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

Then make your static page a folder that accepts a [path]

```
// /pages/my-page/[path].jsx file
import { decodeOptions } from '../../utils'

export async function getStaticProps({
  params,
}) {
  const options = decodeOptions(params.path)
  return {
    props: {
      options,
    }
  }
}

export function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true
  }
}

export default function MyPath({ options }) {
  return <MyPage
    isReturnVisitor={options.returnVisitor}
    country={options.country} />
}
```

And your encoding/decoding functions can be a simple JSON.strinfigy

```
// utils.js
// https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-json-stable-stringify
import stringify from 'fast-json-stable-stringify'

export function encodeOptions(options) {
  const json = stringify(options)
  return encodeURI(json);
}

export function decodeOptions(path) {
  return JSON.parse(decodeURI(path));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a way of doing this

```
const router = useRouter()

useEffect(() => {
    const params = router.query
    console.log(params)
}, [router.query])
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, `useEffect` is for client side only stuff (e.g. that requires `window`), and OP wants to prerender on server.

Comment: I know, but it's impossible to do what he wants without getting the query on client, as next js documentation says: "getStaticProps generates the page at build time. There's no possible way to know the custom query params your visitors can use at build time." The only way us using getServerSideProps. But then you'll lose the static optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to query params in `getStaticProps` since that's only run at build-time on the server.

However, you can use `router.query` in your page component to retrieve query params passed in the URL on the client-side.

```js
// pages/shop.js

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const ShopPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    console.log(router.query) // returns query params object

    return (
        <div>Shop Page</div>
    )
}

export default ShopPage
```

---

If a page does not have data fetching methods, `router.query` will be an empty object on the page's first load, when the page gets pre-generated on the server.

From the [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) documentation:

> `query`: `Object` - The query string parsed to an object. It will be
> an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't have [data
> fetching
> requirements](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).
> Defaults to `{}`

As [@zg10 mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68617162/1870780), you can solve this by using the `router.isReady` property in a `useEffect`'s dependencies array.

From the [`next/router` object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) documentation:

> `isReady`: `boolean` - Whether the router fields are updated
> client-side and ready for use. Should only be used inside of
> `useEffect` methods and not for conditionally rendering on the server.

Comment: Actually on the first load don't have any query string. After the action query string generates in the URL.  So the first load will return a null value and give an error.

Comment: Can't you check the query string after that "action" happens? Same logic applies. If you could add your code to the question, that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have access to the query string (`?a=b`) for **SSG** (which is static content - always the same - executed only on build time).

But if you *have to use query string variables* then you can:

1. still statically pre-render content on build time (**SSG**) or on the fly (**ISR**) and handle this route by rewrite ([next.config.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewrite-parameters) or [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware))
2. use **SSR**
3. use [**CSR**](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side) (can also use [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/))